# php error when using get request

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to select and insert into a database with PDO. When I pass my parameters in the url it works perfectly. But when there is nothing in the url, i get 2 errors.

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp64\www\MT\magiclogin.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp64\www\MT\magiclogin.php on line 20
```

Post works perfectly but i want to send it through the url and remove the html. But every time i reload the page i get the error. Here is my code

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =="GET"){

    try{

        // new php data object 
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicsever', 'root', '');
        //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die("There was an error connecting to the database");   

    }



    $username = trim($_GET['username']); 
    $password = trim($_GET['password']);

    $stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE username = ?");

    $stmt->execute(array($username));

    if($row = $stmt->fetch()){

        $hashedPassword = md5(md5($row['user_id']).$_GET['password']);

        if($hashedPassword == $row['password']){

            $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $stmtTokenCheck = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM token_table WHERE token = ?");

            $stmtTokenCheck->execute(array($token));

            if($rowToken = $stmtTokenCheck->fetch()){

                $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            }   

            $time = time();
            $stmt = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO token_table (timestamp, user_id, token)VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->execute(array($time, $row['user_id'], $token));

            echo json_encode([

                "timestamp" => $time,
                "token" => $token,
                "fullname" => $row['fullname'],
                "username" => $row['username'],
                "email" => $row['email']
            ]);

        }else{

            die("Password or Username entered is incorrect!");
        }

    }else{

            die("Password or Username entered is incorrect!");
        }





}




?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no username or password arguments in the url query (The portion of the url that comes after `?`) then your $_GET array will be empty.

You should check that these arguments are not empty before trying to do logic with them:

```
if (!empty($_GET['username']) && !empty($_GET['password')) {
  // trim and db stuff here
}
```

Also must note that it is not secure to send a password through the url query.  Further, md5 is not sufficient for encrypting passwords.  Look into PHP's [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Comment: I tried that but i got other errors. And is it better to use post instead for the password?

Comment: Yes it's better to use POST otherwise the user's password will be visible for all to see in the URL.

Comment: Will this make it easier for someone to hack and take the information. And do you think my form is good and will be less likely to get sql injected?

Comment: Yes using prepared statements is good for avoiding sql injection.  Your form doesn't have any obvious risk of being hacked, but the issue is if your user data is exposed somehow, the passwords can be easily decrypted because you are not using a strong one way encryption.

Comment: Wow you are amazing thank you for answering my questions and more :D

Comment: if(!empty($_GET['username']) && !empty($_GET['password'])){
edit the code because you're missing some stuff :D

Answer (score 1):

What if you try this in your first line:

```
if(isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password'])) {

...
```

instead of `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =="GET"){`

Comment: OH THAT WORKED! So your checking if data was entered ?

Comment: Yep! It checks if these variables exist and are passed via GET. Glad I could help! In any case, I think you should be using POST for security...

Comment: I dont think isset is quite correct here since you can set username and password to empty strings which pass the isset check but unless you are doing further validation it isn't sufficient.